# Is it allowed to swap derivative and improper integral

Tags: calculus

**Def.**

$$
f: \; (0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad r \mapsto \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \frac{\sin(rx)}{x} dx
$$

My exercise was to show that $f'(r) = \frac{1}{1+r^2}$.

I solved this by doing

$$
\frac{d}{dr}  \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \frac{\sin(rx)}{x} dx \color{red}{=}  \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dr} e^{-x} \frac{\sin(rx)}{x} dx
$$

but I am unsure under which circumstances $\color{red}{=}$ holds. Is there a simple proof I can take for this?

**EDIT**

I do not know about *Leibniz Integral Rule* or anything like that.

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are allowed to take derivatives inside the integral in this case, because:

1. $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \frac{\sin(r\,x)}{x}\,dx$ converges for all $r>0$.
2. $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin(r\,x)\,dx$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.